# Creating an error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I'm trying to create an error message to display to the user but it doesn't seem to work. The error message is supposed to get additional messages into it if user input is missing, and then display all the errors (in red), each in one line, in a span.

```
        $(function() {
            $("#intButton").click(function() {
                var errorMsg = "";
                $errorMsg = $(errorMsg);
                $($errorMsg).css("color", "red");
                if (!$("#intMin").val()) $($errorMsg).append("<p>Enter a minimum value!</p>");
                if (!$("#intMax").val()) $($errorMsg).append("<p>Enter a maximum value!</p>");
                $("#intResult").text($($errorMsg).text());
            });
        });
```

HTML:

```
Min:<input type="text" id="intMin">
Max:<input type="text" id="intMax">
Result: <span id="intResult"></span>
```

This displays no errors at all and it simply doesn't work. Nothing is shown within the span.

http://jsfiddle.net/kWTkT/1/

Comment: You are creating a jQuery element several times with $($errorMsg).

Comment: what's the purpose of 
var errorMsg = "";
                $errorMsg = $(errorMsg);

Comment: don't you use some HTML code somewhere in your page? You should provide a jsfiddle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much easier way would be to simply create a CSS class `error`:

```
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

Then just add the class to the `p` element on `append`:

```
$("#intButton").click(function() {
    var errorMsg = "";
    if (!$("#intMin").val()) errorMsg += "Enter a minimum value. <br />";
    if (!$("#intMax").val()) errorMsg += "Enter a maximum value. ";

    //Display the error:
    $("#intResult").html("<p class='error'>" + errorMsg + "</p>");
});
```

Comment: If both fields are empty, won't the second error overwrite the first one in your code, instead of showing both?

Comment: It will, OP can throw a check in for both empty, shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: That might be problematic - the reason I wanted to create an error message and append to it is because there might be more than 2 errors at a time, and there are more types of possible errors.

Comment: @frrlod -- Does this accomplish what you need?

Comment: Almost! But since ALL the error message is within a paragraph, it ends up being on one line. I would like each error to be on a different line.

Comment: @frrlod -- I put a `<br/>` tag into the error message, because of this we also have to append with `.html()` to recognize the HTML.\

Comment: Works! Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

check wether your looking for this

```
<html><head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">  
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-git.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="">
  Min:
<input type="text" id="intMin">
<br>
<br>Max:
<input type="text" id="intMax">
<br>
    <input type="button" value="click" id="intButton">
<br>Result: <span id="intResult"></span>
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 

        $(function() {
            $("#intButton").click(function() {
                var errorMsg = "";
                console.log('enter');
                $errorMsg = $(errorMsg);
                $($errorMsg).css("color", "red");
                if ($("#intMin").val()=='') $('#intResult').append("<p>Enter a minimum value!</p>");
                if ($("#intMax").val()=='') $('#intResult').append("<p>Enter a maximum value!</p>");

            });
        });
//]]>  

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kWTkT/2/)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep each error message within a separate paragraph tag you could do something like:

CSS

```
.errorResults{ 
    color: red; 
}
```

HTML

```
Min: <input type="text" id="intMin" /><br />
Max: <input type="text" id="intMax" /><br />
Result: <span id="intResult" class="errorResults" ></span><br />
<button id="intButton">Test</button>
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $("#intButton").click(function () {
        var errorMsg = "";
        if (!$("#intMin").val()) {
            errorMsg += "<p>Enter a minimum value!</p>";
        }
        if (!$("#intMax").val()) {
            errorMsg += "<p>Enter a maximum value!</p>";
        }
        $("#intResult").html(errorMsg);
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t3ZSH/)